# Instalar PHP 5.6 en Debian 9.11

Tags: servidor, php5, instalacion, debian-9, dependencias

Buen día todos, estoy tratando de instalar **php5.6** en mi servidor **Debian 9.11**

En el servidor ya está instalado php7, pero por compatibilidad con aplicaciones que estamos manejando necesito cambiarlo a php5.

El problema es que todos los métodos que encontré en internet para obtenerlo fallan porque dependen del comando

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

(el tuto más completo que encontré fue [este](http://www.ingdiaz.org/cambiar-version-php-7-0-php-5-6-ubuntu-16-04/), combinado con [este](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-add-apt-repository-on-debian-ubuntu/)) que arroja el siguiente error:

```
gpg: Total number processed: 1  
gpg: imported: 1  
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found. 
Exception in thread Thread-1: Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 688, in addkey_func
    func(**kwargs)   
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 386, in add_key
    return apsk.add_ppa_signing_key()   
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 273, in add_ppa_signing_key
    cleanup(tmp_keyring_dir)   
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 234, in cleanup
    shutil.rmtree(tmp_keyring_dir)   
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 480, in rmtree
    _rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror)   
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 438, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())   
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 436, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    os.unlink(name, dir_fd=topfd) 
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No existe el fichero o el directorio: 'S.gpg-agent.ssh'
```

Leí que en Ubuntu recomendaban borrar /etc/apt/trusted.gpg pero en mi Debian no tengo ese archivo

¿Alguien sabe cómo darme una mano?

> EDITADO: Tengo otros servidores creados anteriormente, Debian 9.11 y Ubuntu 18.04 también, donde tengo esta versión de php, pero no logro instalarlo en este